# Processing wireless frames with pcap

Tags: wifi, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture

I am working on a project that involves interacting with the data in 802.11 frames. I am using libpcap 1.0. I have written code from most of the tutorials on the website as well as online that I could find, but most are geared towards sniffing over ethernet. I am using a mac for my packet captures. Does anyone know of a resource I could use as a guide for sniffing wireless frames and extracting data. I have some experience with c/c++ but am not an expert and just need a place to start with understanding the differences involved with processing the 802.11 frames with pcap.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It did help alot im still having problems my output isn't matching up to wireshark I'm trying to find information about differences in the radiotap header for mac os X

Comment: Many implementations support radiotap headers. An old experimental project of mine did some raw 802.11 frame capture. I was working with Linux, but there might be some value there for you https://github.com/IronSavior/wifoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **linux** environment, you should use **libpcap** library available at http://www.tcpdump.org 
and use the **manual** given on http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html.

You won't need any tutorials if you read above manual page. Still you can see a classic example to read packets from a network interface given on http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html

If you are working on **windows**, you can use **Winpcap** and use http://www.winpcap.org/docs/ to understand its functions.

But I will highly suggest **Jnetpcap** (http://jnetpcap.com) library if you know Java.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing ;)
then I wrote about it http://pcap-wireless.blogspot.com/2011/11/post-1.html

Answer (score 0):

[tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html)
 [Pcap tutorial](http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html)
[Processing incorrect mac addresses from 802.11 frames with pcap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203419/processing-incorrect-mac-addresses-from-802-11-frames-with-pcap) has some related info on some pitfalls I encountered when processing frames by incorrectly using the pcap api's and issues caused by the radiotap headers as well. 
[Another tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/packet-sniffing-using-libpcap/).

Hopefully these help.