# Processing incorrect mac addresses from 802.11 frames with pcap

Tags: c, macos, wifi, pcap, libpcap

I'm working throurgh a project with pcap and wireless. Following an example posted in response to oe of my earlier questions I am trying to extract the mac addresses from wireless frames. I have created structures for the radiotap header and a basic management frame. For some reason when it comes to trying to output the mac addresses I am printing out the wrong data. When I compare to wireshark I don't see why the radio tap data is printing out correctly but the mac addresses are not. I don't see any additional padding in the hex dump that wireshark displays when i look at the packets and compare the packets that I have captured. I am somewhat famialar with c but not an expert so maybe I am not using the pointers and structures properly could someone help show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Quentin

```
//  main.c
//  MacSniffer
//


#include <pcap.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXBYTES2CAPTURE 65535

#ifdef WORDS_BIGENDIAN
typedef struct frame_control
{
    unsigned int subtype:4; /*frame subtype field*/
    unsigned int protoVer:2; /*frame type field*/
    unsigned int version:2; /*protocol version*/

    unsigned int order:1;  
    unsigned int protected:1;
    unsigned int moreDate:1;
    unsigned int power_management:1;

    unsigned int retry:1; 
    unsigned int moreFrag:1;
    unsigned int fromDS:1;
    unsigned int toDS:1;
}frame_control;

struct ieee80211_radiotap_header{
    u_int8_t it_version;
    u_int8_t it_pad;
    u_int16_t it_len;
    u_int32_t it_present;
    u_int64_t MAC_timestamp;
    u_int8_t flags;
    u_int8_t dataRate;
    u_int16_t channelfrequency;
    u_int16_t channFreq_pad;
    u_int16_t channelType;
    u_int16_t channType_pad;
    u_int8_t ssiSignal;
    u_int8_t ssiNoise;
    u_int8_t antenna;
};

#else
typedef struct frame_control
{
    unsigned int protoVer:2; /* protocol version*/
    unsigned int type:2; /*frame type field (Management,Control,Data)*/
    unsigned int subtype:4; /* frame subtype*/

    unsigned int toDS:1; /* frame coming from Distribution system */
    unsigned int fromDS:1; /*frame coming from Distribution system */
    unsigned int moreFrag:1; /* More fragments?*/
    unsigned int retry:1; /*was this frame retransmitted*/

    unsigned int powMgt:1; /*Power Management*/
    unsigned int moreDate:1; /*More Date*/
    unsigned int protectedData:1; /*Protected Data*/
    unsigned int order:1; /*Order*/
}frame_control;

struct ieee80211_radiotap_header{
    u_int8_t it_version;
    u_int8_t it_pad;
    u_int16_t it_len;
    u_int32_t it_present;
    u_int64_t MAC_timestamp;
    u_int8_t flags;
    u_int8_t dataRate;
    u_int16_t channelfrequency;
    u_int16_t channelType;
    int ssiSignal:8;
    int ssiNoise:8;
};
#endif
struct wi_frame {
    u_int16_t fc;
    u_int16_t wi_duration;
    u_int8_t wi_add1[6];
    u_int8_t wi_add2[6];
    u_int8_t wi_add3[6];
    u_int16_t wi_sequenceControl;
    // u_int8_t wi_add4[6];
    //unsigned int qosControl:2;
    //unsigned int frameBody[23124];
};

void processPacket(u_char *arg, const struct pcap_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char* packet)
{
    int i= 0, *counter = (int *) arg;
    struct ieee80211_radiotap_header *rh =(struct ieee80211_radiotap_header *)packet;
    struct wi_frame *fr= (struct wi_frame *)(packet + rh->it_len);
    u_char *ptr;
    //printf("Frame Type: %d",fr->wi_fC->type);
    printf("Packet count: %d\n", ++(*counter));
    printf("Received Packet Size: %d\n", pkthdr->len);
    if(rh->it_version != NULL)
    {
      printf("Radiotap Version: %d\n",rh->it_version);
    }
    if(rh->it_pad!=NULL)
    {
      printf("Radiotap Pad: %d\n",rh->it_pad);
    }
    if(rh->it_len != NULL)
    {
        printf("Radiotap Length: %d\n",rh->it_len);
    }
    if(rh->it_present != NULL)
    {
        printf("Radiotap Present: %c\n",rh->it_present);
    }
    if(rh->MAC_timestamp != NULL)
    {
        printf("Radiotap Timestamp: %u\n",rh->MAC_timestamp);
    }

    if(rh->dataRate != NULL)
    {
        printf("Radiotap Data Rate: %u\n",rh->dataRate);
    }
    if(rh->channelfrequency != NULL)
    {
        printf("Radiotap Channel Freq: %u\n",rh->channelfrequency);
    }
    if(rh->channelType != NULL)
    {
    printf("Radiotap Channel Type: %06x\n",rh->channelType);
    }
    if(rh->ssiSignal != NULL)
    {
        printf("Radiotap SSI signal: %d\n",rh->ssiSignal);
    } 
    if(rh->ssiNoise != NULL)
    {
        printf("Radiotap SSI Noise: %d\n",rh->ssiNoise);
    } 

ptr = fr->wi_add1;
int k= 6;
printf("Destination Address:");
do{
    printf("%s%X",(k==6)?" ":":",*ptr++);
}
while(--k>0);
printf("\n");

ptr = fr->wi_add2;
k=0;
printf("Source Address:");
do{
    printf("%s%X",(k==6)?" ":":",*ptr++);
}while(--k>0);
printf("\n");

ptr = fr->wi_add3;
k=0;
do{
    printf("%s%X",(k==6)?" ":":",*ptr++);
}
while(--k>0);
printf("\n");
/* for(int j = 0; j < 23124;j++)
 {
 if(fr->frameBody[j]!= NULL)
 {
 printf("%x",fr->frameBody[j]);
 }
 }
 */
for (i = 0;i<pkthdr->len;i++)
{

    if(isprint(packet[i +rh->it_len]))
    {
        printf("%c",packet[i + rh->it_len]);    
    }

    else{printf(".");}



    //print newline after each section of the packet
    if((i%16 ==0 && i!=0) ||(i==pkthdr->len-1))
    {
        printf("\n");
    }

}
return;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

int count = 0;
pcap_t* descr = NULL;
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE], *device = NULL;
struct bpf_program fp;
char filter[]="wlan broadcast";
const u_char* packet;
memset(errbuf,0,PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE);
device = argv[1];

if(device == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"Supply a device name ");
}

descr = pcap_create(device,errbuf);
pcap_set_rfmon(descr,1);
pcap_set_promisc(descr,1);
pcap_set_snaplen(descr,30);
pcap_set_timeout(descr,10000);

pcap_activate(descr);
int dl =pcap_datalink(descr);
printf("The Data Link type is %s",pcap_datalink_val_to_name(dl));
//pcap_dispatch(descr,MAXBYTES2CAPTURE,1,512,errbuf);
//Open device in promiscuous mode
//descr = pcap_open_live(device,MAXBYTES2CAPTURE,1,512,errbuf);

/* if(pcap_compile(descr,&fp,filter,0,PCAP_NETMASK_UNKNOWN)==-1)
 {
 fprintf(stderr,"Error compiling filter\n");
 exit(1);
 }

 if(pcap_setfilter(descr,&fp)==-1)
 {
 fprintf(stderr,"Error setting filter\n");
 exit(1);
 }
 */
pcap_loop(descr,0, processPacket, (u_char *) &count);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't code for Mac, and generally had a little trouble finding the relevant line. But I recently posted a question on pcap here that got a reply which, under 2., might have something that applies to you. Maybe have a look.

Comment: Resetting `k` to `6` rather than `0` before printing `fr->wi_add2` and `fr->wi_add3` might help, but I don't know if that's the only problem because "printing out the wrong data" isn't very specific.  An example packet hex dump and corresponding "wrong" output would be useful.

Comment: Did you get your code to work? I'm trying to get packets in monitor mode in libpcap but can't seem to read the header properly so I can obtain the mac addresses...

Comment: Hi yeah I took the comments that Guy included below and was able to fix it once I accounted for the radiotap header length and removed the set_snaplen call I was able to get my outputs to line up with wireshark

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing several things wrong.

The *first* thing you're doing wrong is declaring the radiotap header as a structure with more fields than `it_version`, `it_pad`, `it_len`, and `it_present`.  There is *absolutely no guarantee* that on in arbitrary radiotap header there will, for example, be a 64-bit `MAC_timestamp` field following the `it_present` field.  You have to look at the `it_present` field to see which of the fields in the header are actually present.  See [the radiotap Web site](http://www.radiotap.org/) for details on how to process a radiotap header.

Comparing the values of the fields against 0 (or `NULL`) does *not* work - if a field isn't present, it simply *isn't present*.

Your code might happen to work with particular versions of drivers for particular networking adapters on particular OSes, but it might fail if the driver is changed or if you run on a machine with a different type of adapter (for example, Atheros vs. Broadcom adapters on Macs) or if you try to run this on a different operating system (Linux, for example).

If you expect this code to run on a big-endian machine, you will also need to fetch fields from the radiotap header more carefully, as they're all little-endian.  (The `#define` in your code is *not* sufficient for that.)

Except for the byte-order issue, which would show up on a Mac only if you're running on a PowerPC Mac, you *are* correctly skipping past the radiotap header, so that's not the issue.

Also, the MAC timestamp is a 64-bit integer, and on a 32-bit machine it'd have to be printed with `%llu` rather than `%u`.

You should also be checking for errors.  `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()` are presumably not failing if you're seeing packets, so that's probably not the immediate problem, but you should check for failure anyway.  The `pcap_set_` routines are also probably not failing, at least not on Wi-Fi devices, but you should check anyway.

If you're going to assume packets are 802.11+radiotap packets, you should probably at least check to make sure the return value of `pcap_datalink()` is `DLT_IEEE802_11_RADIO` and fail if it's not.  While you're at it, add a newline to the end of the message printed for the link-layer type.

But the *main* think you're doing wrong is capturing no more than 30 bytes of every packet!  When you do `pcap_set_snaplen(descr,30);`, you're saying "don't capture any more than 30 bytes"; the radiotap header is probably longer than that, so you're not even going to get all of the radiotap header, much less getting any of the 802.11 header.

If you want to capture the *entire* packet, just leave the `pcap_set_snaplen()` call out.

Oh, and if you want to be *really* careful, make sure, when you're looking at the radiotap and 802.11 header, that you haven't gone past `pkthdr->caplen`.

That also means your loop that checks `pkthdr->len` should check `pkthdr->caplen` *AND* should either start with packet[0] or should subtract `rh->it_len` from `pkthdr->caplen` (as you should have checked to make sure `rh->it_len` is greater than or equal to `pkthdr->caplen` while or before you parsed the radiotap header, the result of that subtraction will be positive).  The snapshot length includes *all* pseudo-headers such as the radiotap header.

Comment: Thanks. Most of the code is really bad i should have cleaned it up before posting, but thanks for all of the advice on both questions. that you answered for me i'll clean things up and take the hints you gave and try to get things working. Thanks again